# Modern library, document defaulted to be read only when opened, edit with user choice by column formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have tried in two ways as below. Both are working for Office documents. But When clicked on PDF or video files, are not opening, its redirecting to document library itself. Other than office documents should open. Please help me on this.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "=if(indexOf([$ContentTypeId], '0x0120') >= 0, '?id=' + [$FileRef], @currentWeb + '/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc='+ [$UniqueId] + '&action=View')"
  }
}
```

OR

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == '.docx', '?id=' + [$FileRef],@currentWeb + '/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc='+ [$UniqueId] + '&action=View')"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When we open the PDF and mp4 files in SharePoint online, these file links are different from office file links, which made the hyperlink doesn't work.